# Issue with font-size 2em in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

My issue is with Chrome and the font-size that I have applied to a phone number for this website:  http://www.davincispainting.com  The purple div has the phone number.

```
#contact-phone {
height: 20px;
width: 218px;
margin: 9px 0px 0px 0px;
float:right;
position:relative;
color:#2B3F63;
font-family: Arial,Impact,Impact5,Charcoal6,sans-serif;
font-size: 2em;
text-align: left;
background-color: Purple;
}
```

The font appears to be 1 font size larger in Chrome as compared with IE8, IE11, and Firefox.

The site uses CSS 2.1, any idea to correct this would be appreciated.

Comment: A question should contain enough code to actually reproduce the problem. A link to a live page is not enough; the question would not be useful to future visitors after the problem has been solved. And you should specify what “1 font size larger” means.

Comment: According to developer tools in Chrome and Firefox, the computed value of `font-size` for the element is `20px`, when default font size settings are used in the browsers. So on what grounds are you saying that the sizes differ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When using % and ems and you really are struggling with a nested element's font size, sometimes it just makes more sense to switch to 'px' for that particular bit of text.

That said, I looked at your sample site in both Chrome and Firefox and it looks exactly the same to me. Are you sure you didn't accidentally change your browser zoom in Chrome? Perhaps you're viewing the site at 110%.

Now that it's so easy to resize web pages, it's a common problem to accidentally have a site zoomed in or out beyond the default.

(as an aside, since it *is* so easy to resize web pages, the arguments for *not* using px in the first place are becoming less valid. As such, I tend to just use px from the start.)

Comment: I have the ThinkPad widescreen dispay 1600 X 900  with resolution of 1360 X 768

Comment: This does not answer the question. It should have been posted as a comment, except for the px advocacy, which should not have been posted at all.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela how does it not answer the question?

Comment: The question says: “The font appears to be 1 font size larger in Chrome as compared with IE8, IE11, and Firefox”. Apparently it asks why this happens. You are saying that it does not happen, and this may well be true, but it is not an answer.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela sometimes the question isn't answerable and the best we can do is offer alternatives. I prefer it that people give me alternatives rather than ignoring a question if I ask the wrong question. To each their own. That said--as it doesn't happen *to me* I would say I am answering the question by informing them that their problem appears to be unique to their set up--and proposing a common theory as to why: accidentally changing browser zoom. (As the question was marked as the answer already, I guess we won't know if that was actually the issue or not...)